# django tastypie and cross domain json

Tags: django, json, node.js, express

Got a django dev server running on localhost:8000 and a nodejs server on localhost:3000.  I want to import json into the nodejs server but I'm getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/presentation/?format=json. Origin
>   http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

This is my first foray into cross-domain fun so I'm WAY out of my depth.

I've added this to my routes in node (expressjs).

```
app.all('/', function(req, res){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.render('index', {
    title: '...'
  });
});
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data *provider* needs to set a policy for cross domain request (*not the client*, as your expressjs snippets suggests).

[Someone](https://github.com/Frangossauro) posted a gist with a simple Django middleware taking care of injecting the needed headers:

> Middlware to allow's your django server to respond appropriately to cross domain XHR (postMessage html5 API).

- https://gist.github.com/426829

Comment: I am using the gist, but doesnt work for me. Trying to load a simple a json exposed by django/python backend on lookback via a simple jquery. I am using $.getJSON method as well. And have also added the mentioned middleware in my middlewares settings. What could be possibly be wrong? Any specific order in which middleware has to be added? Or do I need to explicitly set headers in each response as well? (Doesnt seem like looking the code of middleware). Or do I need to modify it to work with json mimetype? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think setting headers in both response and request is required. This is updated gist https://gist.github.com/1369619

Answer (score 6):

https://gist.github.com/426829 - This snippet was really useful however doing POST using backbone to django server i had to match **Access-Control-Request-Headers** header on request with **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** on response.

coffee:

```
auth = (xhr) ->
xhr['xhrFields']= {withCredentials: true}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true' )
xhr.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
xhr.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS')
xhr.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control')
```

python: https://gist.github.com/426829 with one extra line

```
def process_request(self, request):

    if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.META:
        response = http.HttpResponse()
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS )
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control"
        return response

    return None
```

Hope this is useful!

Answer (score 1):

You could have also used [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/presentation/?format=jsonp
```

Comment: Great! But how can I customize the callback name?

Comment: include `callback` parameter in the URL. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/presentation?format=jsonp&callback=foo`.

Answer (score 1):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/jakecr/10337880) is a TastyPie resource base class. Any resource subclassing this will be cross-domain accessable.

It's similar to others out there but will add CORS headers to *all* respones a TastyPie resource may give. This includes error responses and ImmediateHttpResponse exceptions

```
from tastypie.resources import Resource
from tastypie.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse


class CorsResource(Resource):

    """ adds CORS headers for cross-domain requests """

    def patch_response(self, response):

        allowed_headers = ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']

        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = ','.join(allowed_headers)
        return response

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ calls super and patches resonse headers
            or
            catches ImmediateHttpResponse, patches headers and re-raises
        """

        try:
            response = super(CorsResource, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.patch_response(response)
        except ImmediateHttpResponse, e:
            response = self.patch_response(e.response)
            # re-raise - we could return a response but then anthing wrapping
            # this and expecting an exception would be confused
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response)

    def method_check(self, request, allowed=None):
        """ Handle OPTIONS requests """
        if request.method.upper() == 'OPTIONS':

            if allowed is None:
                allowed = []

            allows = ','.join([s.upper() for s in allowed])

            response = HttpResponse(allows)
            response['Allow'] = allows
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=response)

        return super(CorsResource, self).method_check(request, allowed)
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Just changed Resource to ModelResource in the class header.

Answer (score 1):

There is a friendly and configurable Django module for this: [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

Answer (score 0):

Setting dataType: 'text' instead of 'jsonp' in the ajax POST code worked for me.